# Installing Telit device wise asset gateway on Raspberry Pi errors with status=203 when starting service

Tags: linux, service, raspberry-pi, iot, telit

I am following the instructions [here](https://docs.devicewise.com/Content/Products/GatewayDevelopersGuide/InstallingProductSoftware/Installing-Asset-Gateway-for-Raspberry-Pi-3.htm) to install Telit asset gateway on my Raspberry Pi. This is a fresh install of 64-bit Pi OS running on a Pi 4.

Installation seems to go well and I get the message

```
Updating file permissions...
Running post-install commands...
systemd detected, installing deviceWISE services
Installation is complete.
```

I then check to see if the service is running using `systemctl status devicewise.service` and it returns this:

```
● devicewise.service - deviceWISE Asset Gateway
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/devicewise.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-12-07 17:19:36 GMT; 19ms ago
   Main PID: 2846
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4164)
        CPU: 6ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/devicewise.service

Dec 07 17:19:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started deviceWISE Asset Gateway.
Dec 07 17:19:36 raspberrypi systemd[2846]: devicewise.service: Failed to execute /opt/dw/dwcore/dwcore: No such file or directory
Dec 07 17:19:36 raspberrypi systemd[2846]: devicewise.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/dw/dwcore/dwcore: No such file or di>
Dec 07 17:19:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: devicewise.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Dec 07 17:19:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: devicewise.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

If I then try again it shows this:

```
    ● devicewise.service - deviceWISE Asset Gateway
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/devicewise.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-12-07 17:19:55 GMT; 2s ago
    Process: 2852 ExecStart=/opt/dw/dwcore/dwcore (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 2852 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 6ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telit requires the 32-bit version of Raspberry Pi OS to be running. Hopefully there will be a 64-bit version of DeviceWise for ARM in the near future.